# Scoring Methodology

Tags: scoring

Consider a the below provided sample data;

```
| Emp.Name | Ahead(%) | OnTime(%)  | Deviation(%) |
---------------------------------------------------
|   Tom    |    5     |    55      |      40      |
|  Edwin   |   100    |     0      |       0      |
|   Paul   |    0     |    100     |       0      |
```

Ahead - Task Completion before alloted time

OnTime - Task completion within alloted time

Deviation - Task completion after alloted time

I would like to rate employee's based on their performance. If an employee is ahead then score him high and if he is performing within time (on-time), then nominal score to him, if he is deviated then reduce score points.

Any suggestion on the Scoring Algorithm or Ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It simply depends how you want to reward/penalize tasks completed ahead/late and whether you need the score to be normalized.

For instance:

- 0 for late
- .5 for on-time
- 1 for early

Then divide by the total number of tasks assigned to the employee. That gives you a score between 0 and 100%:

```
| Emp.Name | Ahead(%) | OnTime(%)  | Deviation(%) |  Score  |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   Tom    |    5     |    55      |      40      |  32.5%  |
|  Edwin   |   100    |     0      |       0      | 100.0%  |
|   Paul   |    0     |    100     |       0      |  50.0%  |
```